# Justification for an Enterprise Antivirus software and a Firewall

Tags: antivirus

Am doing a project on the need to have both an Antivirus apps and Firewall in an Enterprise environment. Can someone kindly provide some justifications for having both instead of one one.

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, you can't ask us to do all your research for you. These are two different animals and they both serve their own purpose.

Comment: Let me Google that for you: "why have firewall and antivirus"

Answer (score 4):

Traditionally, a firewall application blocks network access based on rules, while an anti-virus solution scans the traffic that is *allowed* by the firewall for viruses. Thus they serve different purposes and you ought to have both. That being said, it is common for software packages that started out as pure firewalls to add anti-virus features and vice versa.